# How do I resize a drawing in a processing applet?

Tags: resize, processing

I imported the processing language into Java and I drew a simple house.

Like:

```java
  rect (75, 175, 350, 175);

  // door

  rect (225, 275, 50, 75);

  // roof
  triangle (250, 100, 75, 175, 425, 175);

  // windows
  rect (125, 200, 50, 50);
  rect (325, 200, 50, 50);
```

I want to be able to resize the image, or scale that image when I change the window size.  Right now the window size is just 500 by 500, but if I expand the window it doesn't expand the drawing with it.

I tried using scale(), but for some reason it scaled the image for like a millisecond and then reverted back to the unscaled version.  My java teacher told me the draw method in processing refreshes at something like 60 times per second, but I don't see why it would be different from the first time.

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mcve], not just a few disconnected lines of code. Right now it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want your drawing to scale with the window, you're going to need to base all your coordinates off the `width` and `height` variables.

For example, let's say I'm drawing a `200x200` circle inside a `200x200` window:

```java
size(200, 200);
ellipse(100, 100, 200, 200);
```

If I then change the size of the window to `400x400`, then I have to change the parameters I'm passing into the `ellipse()` function:

```java
size(400, 400);
ellipse(200, 200, 400, 400);
```

This can be annoying (as you're experiencing), so it's better to just base your parameters off the `width` and `height` variables. That way whenever your window size changes, Processing does the calculation for you and the drawing scaled with your window.

```java
size(600, 600);
ellipse(width/2, height/2, width, height);
```

This is just an example, but the process for you would be the same: go through and change every value to be based off the `width` and `height` variables instead of hard-coded numbers.

More info can be found here: [Using Variables - HappyCoding.io](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/using-variables)

(full disclosure: I wrote that tutorial, but I think it explains exactly what you're asking about)

**Edit:** You asked about the `scale()` method, so I'll explain that below. But if you're trying to base the size of your drawing off the size of your window, then you should use the above approach! But since this is a homework assignment, you're restricted to doing it the way the teacher says. Anyway...

Let's look at a simple program:

```java
size(100, 100);
ellipse(50, 50, 10, 10);
```

This code simply creates a `100x100` sized window and then draws a small ellipse in the center:

[image: small circle]

If we wanted to make the circle bigger, we could use the `scale()` function. You can think of the `scale()` function as automatically multiplying every parameter you pass into a drawing function (like `ellipse()` or `rect()`) by whatever number(s) you pass into the `scale()` function.

For example, this code multiplies every number by `2`:

```java
size(100, 100);
scale(2);
ellipse(50, 50, 10, 10);
```

[image: big off-center circle]

The circle is now twice as large, but it's also no longer in the center. That's because we're also multiplying `50,50` (the center of the window) by `2` to get `100,100` (the bottom-right corner of the window). To fix that, we either need to change the `50,50`:

```java
size(100, 100);
scale(2);
ellipse(25, 25, 10, 10);
```

Or we could use the `translate()` function to move the coordinates **before** we do the scale:

```java
size(100, 100);
translate(50, 50);
scale(2);
ellipse(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

Either approach is fine, so it's really up to which one makes more sense to you. Now we have a big centered circle, even though we're still sizing it to `10,10`.

[image: big centered circle]

Comment: Hi Kevin,   I know how to do it this way, but it wasn't what my teacher was asking for.  My teacher told us to use a method in the processing library, and I found that it was actually the scale() method.  You have to set to floats and scale the drawings to the floats.  Thanks anyways!

Comment: @LarryJing I've edited my answer to include information about the `scale()` function.

Comment: Thanks, you explained it very well.